# OpenStack Juno: Is it possible to keep instance on same compute host after resizing?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have OpenStack Juno setup with 1 controller and 3 compute nodes.
I have enabled password less authentication between compute nodes for re-sizing to work.
Instance re-sizing is working fine up till now.

Now due to  some reason I want to remove password less authentication between compute nodes. After removing password less authentication instances will not migrate from one node to another.

So is it possible to keep instance on same compute host after resizing every time? If yes then how?

Environment description:

**Base OS on all nodes:**
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release: 14.04
Code name: trusty.

**OpenStack details:**
Version: Juno.
Hypervisor Type: QEMU
Storage for instances: Ephemeral (Not using cinder)

Answer (score 2):

There is no provision for that yet. Setting 'allow_resize_to_same_host' to 'True' doesn't ensure your requirement.

This setting only allows the same host to be an option while migrating the resized vm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `allow_resize_to_same_host` option to `True`, from the  [OpenStack configuration reference](http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/config-reference/content/list-of-compute-config-options.html#config_table_nova_policy).

Comment: allow_resize_to_same_host  option only allows instance to resize on same node in case of single node. I want some solution or workaround which will force instance to resize on same node even if there are multiple nodes.